# How may I write foreach for that sql query to show messages sender&receiver

Tags: php, sql

I want to show messages as receiver on right and sender on left here's my query below:

```
<?php 

$mesajsor=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mesaj where kullanici_gon=:send_id and kullanici_gel=:receiver_id
 order by mesaj_zaman ASC");
$mesajsor->execute(array(
  'send_id' => $_GET['kullanici_gon'],
  'receiver_id' => $_GET['kullanici_gel']
));



  $say=0;
      while($mesajcek=$mesajsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
        $say++;?>
```

How may I implement the foreach to that query?

```
foreach($messages as $message){

   if($message->kullanici_gel == receiver_id){
     <div class="right">$message</div>

   }elseif($message->kullanici_gon == send_id){
    <div class="left">$message</div>

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this in two separate loops, like this:

```
echo '<div class="right">';
foreach($messages as $message){
   if($message->kullanici_gel == $receiver_id) {
       echo '<div class="message">$message</div>';
   }
}
echo '</div><div class="left">';
foreach($messages as $message){
    if($message->kullanici_gon == $send_id) {
        echo '<div class="message">$message</div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

To prevent writing code twice you could use [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). For instance:

```
function displayMessage($message)
{
    echo '<div class="message">$message</div>';
}

echo '<div class="right">';
foreach($messages as $message){
    if($message->kullanici_gel == $receiver_id) {
        displayMessage($message);
    }
}
echo '</div><div class="left">';
foreach($messages as $message){
    if($message->kullanici_gon == $send_id) {
        displayMessage($message);
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Especially because displaying a message is probably more complicated than you let us believe.